# "Hostname not recognized as belonging to academic domain" when connected via VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

I'm trying to install software which offers free academic licenses for students. To install the license, I have to be connected to the university network. I'm home on holiday, so I'm trying to use the university VPN for the first time. I got access to the VPN, but when I go to install the software, I receive error:

> ERROR 303: hostname [home ip address] not recognized as belonging to an academic domain

It looks as if network traffic is not going over the VPN. Any suggestions for how to go about fixing this? I am on Windows 10.

Edit: When trying to set the default gateway, I do not have an option on windows 10. Here is what I am given:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your VPN isn't configured to route *all* traffic through the VPN, only the traffic that's destined for your university's network. To fix this, look in the properties of your VPN connection for an option such as **Use default gateway on remote network** (which is what the Windows-native VPN configuration calls it) and enable it:

[image]

Comment: I do not have an option to use default gateway on remote network. I posted what screen I am displayed when I go Network and Sharing Center->Change adapter settings->Wi-Fi->Properties->TCP/IPv4->Advanced...

Comment: @RocketSocks22 you need to edit the VPN connection, not your network adapter (Wi-Fi)'s properties. Answer edited to clarify that.

Comment: I am using Cisco AnyConnect as my VPN. I am not seeing anything within the settings there that I can change. Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @RocketSocks22 you're probably looking in the correct place. It's possible the VPN doesn't permit you to set this. Try a Internet search for "Cisco anyconnect Use default gateway on remote network" to see if you're missing something.

Comment: It seems that Cisco anyconnect does not allow this. The work around I've been seeing is something about 'split tunneling', but I have zero background in networking and a lot of it seems to be going over my head

Comment: It seems that the only way to force all traffic through the VPN is to request my IT department to do it. Looks like there is nothing I can do from client side